# Accessing items from a dictionary using pickle efficiently in Python

Tags: python, pickle

I have a large dictionary mapping keys (which are strings) to objects. I pickled this large dictionary and at certain times I want to pull out only a handful of entries from it. The dictionary has usually thousands of entries total. When I load the dictionary using pickle, as follows:

```
from cPickle import *
# my dictionary from pickle, containing thousands of entries
mydict = open(load('mypickle.pickle'))
# accessing only handful of entries here
for entry in relevant_entries:
  # find relevant entry
  value = mydict[entry]
```

I notice that it can take up to 3-4 seconds to load the entire pickle, which I don't need, since I access only a tiny subset of the dictionary entries later on (shown above.)

How can I make it so pickle only loads those entries that I have from the dictionary, to make this faster?

Thanks.

Comment: That's not what pickling is designed for; use a database if you want a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your objects are independent of each others, you could pickle and unpickle them individually using their key as filename, in some perverse way a directory is a kind of dictionary mapping filenames to files. This way it is simple to load only relevant entries.

Basically you use a memory dictionary as cache and if the searched key is missing try to load the file from the filesystem.

I'm not really saying you should do that. A database (ZODB, SQLite, other) is probably better for persistant storage.

Answer (score 3):

Pickle serializes object (hierachies), it's not an on-disk store. As you have seen, you must unpickle the entire object to use it - which is of course wasteful. Use [shelve](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html), [dbm](http://docs.python.org/library/dbm.html) or a database ([SQLite](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html)) for on-disk storage.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to have "Ghost" objects, I.e. objects that are only placeholders and load themselves when accessed. This is a Difficult Issue, but it has been solved. You have two options. You can use the persistence library from ZODB, that helps with this. Or, you just start using ZODB directly; problem solved.

http://www.zodb.org/

Comment: Isn't it a way to replace a problem with a worse problem ? ZODB is not that simple... +1 anyway

Comment: ZODB takes some work to set up, of course, but then it's very easy to use, and it solves this problem. You can have many gigabytes of data with no problems. ZODB is in fact bloody awesome.

Comment: I agree with you, it's awesome. I was just pointing out the entry ticket is not free. But it's a good cost to pay.